# Token balance to 0 on mist

Tags: mist, tokens

**Summary: tokens shown on Mist have a balance of 0, while I can see a positive balance on etherscan.**
**DISCLAIMER: My geth is sync & I did add the token under the contracts tab.**

I have some tokens in a ETH wallet I made using Mist. My Mist version is the latest (9.2), under ubuntu. Some Tokens I bought, some others I received by airdrop, like Xenon. They are all ERC-20. As everybody who has ether received some xenons, I will use this one as example. I can see them all on etherscan.io but it is stuck to 0 on Mist (and ethereumwallet).

No other question accross the web is helpful. When there are answers, they speak of some functions that I have no idea about (these functions don't work on the `mist>toggle develop tool>mist UI>console`).

Steps I have done:

- Went to Contracts tab
- clicked "add token" under "custom tokens"
- entered Xenon address : 0xab95E915c123fdEd5BDfB6325e35ef5515F1EA69
- entered Xenon under token name
- entered XNN under token symbol
- entered 18 under decimals

It shows 0.

My geth is sync in "light" mode. Back in the days, it was synced in normal mode, token balance was also 0 so the light mode is not the root of the problem. (not syncing in normal mode anymore, too slow).

I have tried the following:

- added the token contract under "custom contracts", JSON interface was the one I found on etherscan: https://etherscan.io/address/0xab95e915c123fded5bdfb6325e35ef5515f1ea69 (under contract source, copied contract ABI). Did not help.
- deleted all files under `/home/[username]/.config/Mist` (folder can be found under `file>backup>application data`) and restarted. Did not help.

Other possibly useful info:

- I have a single account under the Wallets tab. It has >1 ether. There is no wallet contracts listed.
- in the contracts tab, there is nothing else than the xenon custom contracts, the xenon token or the unicorns token (by default after fresh install of mist).
- there are two errors showing up in the developper window that look irrelevant to my issue (unless the SourceSansPro font is used to show balance > 0?):

|                                                                 |

```
SourceSansPro.otf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/sockjs/info?cb=h2d0g47fwv Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: In my best impersonation of Sherlock Holmes: When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth. Are you looking at the same wallet address in both places?

Comment: Thanks Sherlock! Yes it's sure, i copied and pasted the address from my mist to etherscan. Also i had to send the ether from the same address to get some other tokens. So I did do everything i was supposed to. Last resort is install/uninstall. I'll try from Windows

Comment: Watson here! Are you sure you're working in the same network? Can you exclude Mist is synced with ropsten instead of mainnet?

Comment: I guess yes, otherwise i could not have bought some of the tokens as i used mist to buy them. Also other networks are greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set up the ethereum wallet on windows and imported my wallets. All my tokens appeared as planned.

Solution: run it on windows.